# Cannot enable active directory user using net-ldap

Tags: ruby, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, netldap

We're experiencing an issue trying to enable a active directory user(`windows server 2012 r2`) using the `net/ldap` library.

### Setup

First, we create a user via this method:

```
def create_user(attrs)
  dn = "cn=#{attrs[:cn]},cn=Users,#{@base}"
  cn = attrs[:cn]
  pass = ascii_convert(attrs[:pwd])
  updated_attrs = { cn: cn,
                    objectclass: ['user'],
                    samaccountname: cn,
                    userprincipalname: "#{attrs[:cn]}@#{@domain}",
                    unicodepwd: pass
  }

  @connection.add(dn: dn, attributes: updated_attrs)
  result = @connection.get_operation_result
  raise LdapError.new("Create AD user error: #{result}") if result.code   != 0
end
```

This creates the user, and by default sets their `userAccountControl` attribute to `546` (which is what we want), when inspected in active directory this shows as:

`0x222 (ACCOUNTDISABLE|PASSWD_NOTREQD|NORMAL_ACCOUNT)`.

### Problem

Later we want to enable that user so we call:

```
def enable_user!(dn, cn)
  u = search_query(find_user(cn)).try(:first)
  if u
    @connection.replace_attribute(dn, :useraccountcontrol, '512')
  else
    false
  end
end
```

However, if I print `@connection.get_operation_result` I get:

`<OpenStruct code=53, error_message="0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n\u0000", matched_dn="", message="Unwilling to perform">`

With this method we want the `userAccountControl` to equal `512`, which is the equivalent of `0x200 (NORMAL_ACCOUNT)`.

### Things I've Tried

notes: connection is over SSL (LDAPS), and bound to an admin AD account.

- [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349593/how-to-modify-useraccountcontrol-in-activedirectory-from-rubyonrails3-with-ruby1)
- using `#modify` instead of `#replace_attribute` in the `enable_user!` method.
- passing the hex values instead of the integer representation.
- perform the same modification using apache directory studio.

One interesting thing I did notice, is that I can modify `useraccountcontrol` to `514` which is:

`0x202 (ACCOUNTDISABLE|NORMAL_ACCOUNT)`

So, it seems I can modify this attribute as long as it's remaining disabled, as soon as I try to change to enabled is when I see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `0000052D` is a [system error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Specifically, it means:

> ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION
>
> 1325 (0x52D)
>
> Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain.

The problem would seem to be that the account you're enabling has a password-policy applied to it, whereby enabling it that password-policy would not be met.

I would first figure out what the password policy is for the account, then set the password to something that meets that policy criteria before flipping the bit to enable it.

If, however, you really want the user to be able to login with no password then the password should be set to null. But I'm not sure under what circumstances that would be desirable.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had time to really dig into this.  However, I think your on the right track.  I believe there is an issue with how I encoded the password in the initial `create_user` method, thus not meeting password requirements.

Comment: That could be the case. The `unicodePwd` expects a pretty specific encoding (UTF-16LE) and I'm not too sure what your `ascii_convert` is doing. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32199465/2242593) might be of some help for that.

Comment: @treiff @ChadSikorra I am getting a different error message. `#<OpenStruct code=53, error_message="00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C04256F, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v2580\x00", matched_dn="", message="Unwilling to perform">` Has anyone ever been able to successfully enable/disable user?

Comment: @SandeepM I would start a new question with the specifics of the code you're using and that error message. That's a different error code than the OP had.